# How to construct a grammar $G$ such that $L(G) = \{ a^nb^m|n \neq 2m,m,n \ge 0\} $?

Tags: computer-science, automata

Construct a grammar $G$ such that $$L(G) = \{ a^nb^m|n \neq 2m,m,n \ge  0\}$$

**My attempt:**

I first constructed a grammar for the langugage $L(G_1) = \{ a^nb^m|n = 2m,m,n \ge = 0\}$,

$G_1 = (\{ S\}, \{a,b\},P,S) $ where $P$ consists of $S\to aaSb|\lambda$

For violating this condition, I modified the above as
$G = (\{ S,A,B\}, \{a,b\},P,S) $ where $P$ consists of $$S\to aaSb|A, A\to aBb, B\to aB|bB|\lambda$$
My question is this correct? If not where exactly I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grammar 
\begin{align}
S &\to aSbb \mid A \\
A &\to aBb \mid A \\
B &\to aB \mid \lambda
\end{align}
does not work because of two issues. First, did you mean $\{a^{2m}b^{m}\}$ or $\{a^{n}b^{2n}\}$? Second thing is that in your grammar $\#b \leq 2\cdot\#a$, but $L$ should include words like $b^{123}$. What you could do is split the grammar into two:

$$L_1 = \{a^nb^m\mid n > 2m \geq 0\},$$
$$L_2 = \{a^nb^m\mid 0 \leq n < 2m\}.$$

Then $G_1$ would be 
\begin{align}
S_1 &\to aaS_1b \mid A, \\
A &\to aA \mid a,
\end{align}

and $G_2$ 
\begin{align}
S_2 &\to aaS_2b \mid aB \mid B, \\
B &\to bB \mid b.
\end{align}

Some other (maybe more intuitive) $S_2$ could look like:

\begin{align}
S_2 &\to AAS_2b \mid Ab,\\
A &\to a \mid \lambda.
\end{align}

Hope this helps ;-)

**Edit 1:** I see that you fixed your grammar, but now you can create words like $ba$ which should not be in the language.

**Edit 2:** Expanded abbreviations into proper CFG and added second version of $S_2$.

Comment: Thanks, but could you please explain what does $b^+,ab^+,a^+b$ means?

Comment: It's a regular expression, a shorthand for $B$ where $B \to bB \mid b$.

Comment: So do you mean: $S_1 \to aaS_1b \mid aBb \mid aB$?

Comment: I expanded the grammar, it should be more clear now.